# JavaScript intellisense colors irregular in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Just installed Visual Studio 2015 Pro (v14.0.25123.0) and found that it is not coloring JavaScript in an expected fashion. See here for an example:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/574x179q90/921/j3Ti2j.png

Also, under "Fonts and Colors", there are no items in the list which begin with "JavaScript" or even "Script". However there are items for everything else, eg. "CSS ...", "HTML ...", "LESS ...", etc.

Is this a bug in VS intellisense, or am I missing something?

---

**EDIT:** Found one problem, which is I was missing `type="text/javascript"` in the `<script>` tag. Apparently VS 2015 intellisense won't assume the language is JavaScript without it. I still have the "missing script color options" problem though. See: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/430x200q90/924/tUglxB.png

Comment: Try to declare object: `var obj = { delete: 0 }`. You will get same result :)

Answer (score 0):

When you change association to a specific file in Windows with an eternal app the code colors turn to black if Visual Studio can't identify the file extension without type=. Try going to Tools-Options and find specific option Extension, there you can add specific type to each extension.